# How to update existing Observable in async pipe

Tags: angular, observable, async-pipe

I have an Observable that is subscribed to via the async-pipe.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="invitations$ | async as invitations">
```

This Observable is set in the ngOnInit:

```
this.invitations$ = this.getInvitations();
```

getInvitations is a private function that does the http-call and returns an `Observable<Invitation[]>`.

```
 private getInvitations(): Observable<Invitation[]> {
    return this.invitationService.getInvitations();
 }
```

Now, in a different function, I want to update this Observable, after a http-call has been completed. I want to send a reminder (triggered via a button in the template), and if it succeeds, I want to update the invitations.

```
sendReminder() {
    this.invitationService.postReminderEmail()
      .subscribe();
  }
```

So I have the line:

```
this.invitations$ = this.getInvitations();
```

But where do I put it? I know that the async-pipe will handle the unsubscription from the previous value and will resubscribe when I do this, so no memory leak.

Do I put it in the pipe?

```
   sendReminder() {
        this.invitationService.postReminderEmail().pipe(
         mergeMap(() => this.invitations$ = this.getInvitations())
          .subscribe();
      }
```

I think this line is a synchronous action, and I'm not really returning anything in the `mergeMap` (even though the compiler accepts this), so this does not seem to be right.
I can change the `mergeMap` with `tap`, but I'm not sure about that either.
Putting it in the `subscribe` feels like an indirect nested subscribe (because it will trigger a new subscribe via the async pipe), which I don't want.
Do I make a Subject that the `invitations$` can listen to, and I do a `next()` here, to trigger it? What I don't like about that, is that I have to put an empty array or something in the next to trigger it.

```
this.invitationsSubject.pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.getInvitations()),
      takeUntil(this.destroyed)
    ).subscribe();

    this.invitations$ = this.invitationsSubject.asObservable();
```

Trigger:

```
this.invitationsSubject.next([])
```

This also does not seem to be a good solution (and it is more verbose).

What is the right approach?

Comment: I've done something similar before but you'll struggle to get a clean solution especially without manual subscribe. Not sure if you've used ngrx but it's good at handling this sort of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to update the invitations$ when you send a reminder?

You could just update the invitations$ instead of creating a new observable, angular will unsubscribe from the previous observable.

```
sendReminder(){
this.invitations$ = this.invitationService.postReminderEmail().pipe(switchMap(() => this.getInvitations()));

}
```

Comment: It can be so simple... thanks!
And what if I want a catchError, but I don't want to end the stream and I don't want to update the Observable either, just do nothing with the original Observable in that case?